# Ошибка при скачивании зависимостей через npm i

Tags: javascript, reactjs, консоль, npm, node-modules

нашёл старый react проект без папки 'node modules', при попытке ввести npm i выходит следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из этого понимаю, что за это время вышли обновления, которые надо бы по хорошему установить, но не устанавливать же их всех вручную? как можно автоматизировать данный процесс? или что вообще делать? Спасибо за помощь

Comment: попробуй `npm i --legacy-peer-deeps` похоже, что у тебя сильно новая версия npm

Comment: всё тоже самое. ничего не поменялось